# Android development - can Eclipse / AVD run error free?

Tags: android, sdk, logcat

I am new to Android development and Eclipse. I have been given an Android app and asked to make some simple changes to it. I can build the project and run it in the emulator, but I see some errors in the LogCat window in Eclipse.

I put aside the app I was given and wrote the Hello World app, following the Hello World tutorial on developer.android.com. With this simple app, I was surprised to see many errors and stack dumps in the LogCat window. I closed Eclipse and re-launched it. After waiting for Eclipse to finish initializing, LogCat was empty. Then I started the Hello World app by clicking the run button. After a while entries appeared in LogCat, including many errors.

With such a simple app, copied from the tutorial, I am guessing the errors arise from the development environment and/or virtual device rather than from the app itself, but I would like to be able to run apps without errors.

Is it a reasonable expectation to be able to run Android apps from Eclipse on an AVD without any errors? Or is it the state of the art that the development environment logs many errors and dumps stack traces even when everything is running "normally"?

If it is reasonable, I will pursue each error until I have cleaned up my environment and application. I would prefer this, as I would then know that if errors appear as I continue development, they arise from my application and must be fixed. On the other hand, I can't spend months developing Eclipse and the Android SDK. If I have to learn to live with logs full of error messages, I'll just ignore them unless something crashes.

Note that the Hello World application runs as expected - it appears to be working despite the errors.

I am running Eclipse Indigo SR2 and Android SDK ??? (I don't see a version number for the SDK - the installer is r18 and SDK Manager says there are no updates available) on Windows 7 Professional, 64bit. I am testing with Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Create a filter at logcat to only get events coming from your package/application.

Comment: You could probably get a lot more meaningful response if you posted the content of some of your errors. I have no idea what kind of errors are in your log, but yes it is reasonable to assume that you can run without them.

Comment: Sorry - new to StackOverflow too... I would like to run error free, not ignore the errors from the platform/environment. But I fear my expectation is unreasonable. Let me rephrase: has anyone run any app from Eclipse on Android 4.0.3 AVD without any errors in CatLog - other than by filtering them all out? If so, and I can replicate that, then that's the baseline I want for development. If not, I'm out of line with the community and will learn to live with errors.

Comment: But WHAT errors actually? Giving more information can help others in answering you.

Comment: I appreciate the value of giving specifics of the errors. On the basis that @Tim says no errors is a reasonable expectation, I will start to work on fixing the errors, but to avoid confusion I will open a separate question for each (one at a time). I hope that is appropriate to the site - please let me know if I should be putting them all here.

Comment: The first error I am seeing is from netd: Unable to bind netlink socket: no such file or directory. I found two questions here about this error: one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9442326/1339621) with no answer and the other (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450629/emulator-stock-error-appeard) with an answer I don't understand. I don't want to start another thread on the same error, but don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
adb com.your.package:v
```

or in log cat on the side button (You may need to make this visible by pressing the button with two rectangles in it in log cat) press the plus button and then add an application filter

Comment: See my comment above, yet filters may ultimately be helpful. Should that be "adb logcat com.your.package:v *:s"?

Comment: The errors are usually conning from other apps, they usually shouldn't effect your app at all. If you have a physical device 4.0.3 device you can disable/uninstall any other app that you believe is causing the problem. Logcat is there to log, to debug, its part of the Android system, you will hardly ever get 0 errors from all apps, bloat ware from your manufacture are usually more likely to have errors from experience.